# What's the use dirsync option for mount?

Tags: mount, concurrency

Today I stumbled upon this `mount`'s option:

> `dirsync`
>   All directory updates within the filesystem should be done  synchronously.
>   This  affects  the  following  system calls: creat, link, unlink, symlink,
>   mkdir, rmdir, mknod and rename.

What are some real-life use cases for this option? When would I want to use `dirsync` instead of `sync`?

Comment: Found this: http://lwn.net/2002/0214/a/dirsync.php3

Seems to have a lot of information you may find useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sync` does everything `dirsync` does, plus more. Unfortunately this 'more' is a significant performance penalty. With `sync` enabled, all disk I/O is immediately written to disk. With `dirsync`, only directory operations are immediately written.

The only case I've seen where one might want to use `dirsync` instead of `sync` is in the case of network filesystems. When multiple boxes are working in a shared directory, they might try to create the file at around the same time. One box will create the file, but without `dirsync` on, the file isn't visible to other boxes yet. With `dirsync` on, the file will show up immediately, so the other servers at least know it exists and can now perform file locking on it.

Comment: As an addendum, the article I linked to states that the original motivation for dirsync was to "make the MTA folks happy" which makes sense given how much file locking goes on and how often they use temporary files when processing the queues.

Comment: @JoelDavis Saw that comment, but it doesn't make much sense. The RFC for mail transfer says the entire file must be committed to disk, not just the directory entry.

Comment: Well it's written by Andrew Morton so it's bonafide no matter what our understanding of the logic is. But the file-based operations have to do with queue operations and locking mailbox files. This is transparent to the transmitting client and just how the internals of the MTA are structured. I know most mail admins don't turn on sync operations for the filesystems (for performance reason), so there must be some wiggle room.

Comment: Which RFC are you referring to BTW?

Comment: @JoelDavis [RFC 2821](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821). `It MUST NOT lose the message for frivolous reasons, such as because the host later crashes`. (I do enjoy how they call a crash "frivolous" :-P )

Comment: If that's the criteria then that explains why they use flat files from the get-go rather than just storing everything in memory until it's been processed and queued. It still doesn't require file I/O be sync'd. To fulfill the requirement the MTA would just have to blindly dump what it gets to a file and do an fsync, after which directory operations are the only sticking point.

Comment: For clarity, the assumption I'm making is that it would wait for the fsync before returning the 250 to the SMTP client.

Comment: @JoelDavis Correct, it does not require full sync I/O as in a write to disk for every `write()` call. It only requires that when the `250 OK` is given that it be written to disk. Postfix does this as well. It explicitly calls `fsync` on the files when fully written. You can also call `fsync` on a directory to ensure that the directory is updated as well. You do not need to enable `dirsync` on the mount.

Comment: I don't think I can continue the conversation much farther since I'm at the limit of stuff I either know or can make an educated guess on, but fwiw there has to be some bonafide logic to it. I doubt mm (judging from other comments I've seen from him on other things, and the approach taken by kernel maintainers in general) would be servicing an idle request from MTA vendors especially if the vendors had the ability to control what they had a problem with.